# chained comparison in DolphinDB queries

Tags: performance, dolphindb

I noticed that chained comparison in DolphinDB queries is considerably slower than expected.

For example, for a distributed table "quotes" with more than 2 billion rows, the query

```
timer select avg(bid) as bid, avg(ofr) as ofr from quotes where 2020.12.07<=date<=2020.12.11 group by date, minute(time) as minute
```

is much slower than

```
timer select avg(bid) as bid, avg(ofr) as ofr from quotes where date>=2020.12.07, date<=2020.12.11 group by date, minute(time) as minute
```

The second query is really fast though. Does anyone know how to write a proper chained comparison in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

According DolphinDB manual
https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Queries.html

Filtering conditions with chained comparisons such as `where 2020.12.07<=date<=2020.12.11` will scan all partitions instead of narrowing down relevant partitions. You can either use `where date between 2020.12.07:2020.12.11` or separate inequality constraints for optimal performance.